# OpenLDAP server ignores URI configuration

Tags: openldap, replication

I set up two hosts with OpenLDAP in N-way multi master replication by following [this](http://www.cyrill-gremaud.ch/linux/howto-setup-n-way-multi-master-replication-with-openldap/) website. One of the installations is a Debian 9.2, the other one is Ubuntu 16.04. The troubled Ubuntu host runs the OpenLDAP server without problems since a couple of weeks. However, after I added the replication, it refused to start again.

#### Regular start fails

On the fresh Debian host, the server starts fine - only replication is set up. On the Ubuntu host, OpenLDAP refuses to start. When trying to started with

```
$ service slapd start
```

the syslog says

```
read_config: no serverID / URL match found. Check slapd -h arguments.
```

#### Foreground start fails

The same when run in foreground mode,

```
$ slapd -d -1
```

#### Foreground start with -h works

Surprisingly, it works when appending the `-h` option

```
$ slapd -d -1 -h ldap2.myhost.loc
```

#### Config ignored?

The setting in the configuration seems to be ignored completely:

```
$ grep -v '^$' /etc/ldap/ldap.conf | grep -v '^#'
BASE    dc=myldapdomain,dc=loc
URI ldap://ldap2.myhost.loc
TLS_CACERT  /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

although it is loaded:

```
$ slapd -d -1
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://localhost/)
ldap_init: trying /etc/ldap/ldap.conf
ldap_init: using /etc/ldap/ldap.conf
```

What am I missing on the OpenLDAP installation on the Ubuntu host in order to start the server successfully?

Answer (score -1):

Your `-h` argument to `slapd` should contain an LDAP URI that matches one of the values listed for the `olcServerID` attribute. So following the documentation you linked to you would use `-h "ldapi:// ldap://ldap1.gremaud.local"` (note the `-h` value should be quoted to list multiple whitespace-separated URI's as one value). Without that, my understanding is the server can't work out which server ID is itself from the values of the `olcServerID` attribute, hence the error.

I don't think `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` has anything to do with this, it's a client configuration file.

Comment: I also thought that this was the client config, but as you can see, it is loaded by slapd. I said in my original post that it works with the -h option, but I want it to start properly without this option, so it must be set in a config file.

Comment: So set it. You claim to have followed the documentation you linked to except you've clearly missed step 3; which tells you to edit `/etc/default/slapd` which will result in setting the `-h` option, it even states the error you'll get if you don't do this, matching what you saw in syslog.

Comment: The setting in the /etc/default/slapd is relevant on my Debian host but it is completely ignored in Ubuntu.

Comment: I've looked at the Ubuntu 16.04 slapd package and it still has an `/etc/default/slapd` file with a `SLAPD_SERVICES` variable which is referenced in `/etc/init.d/slapd` so it looks like it would work to me. Does 16.04 also support systemd? I can't find the unit file for slapd but it should have something like `EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/slapd` in it somewhere to achieve the same goal.

Comment: No, even when I bypass all systemv (Debian)/systemd (Ubuntu) with `slapd -d -1`, the Debian installation works, whilst the Ubuntu installation fails...

Comment: Regardless you still need to set `-h` (somehow) for the n-way replication to function, `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` is a client configuration file; the `URI` parameter is for telling client tools like `ldapmodify` where to connect to. If the Ubuntu version doesn't map `$SLAPD_SERVICES` to the `-h` option then you need to pick through whichever init system is in use and work out why it's not getting passed through.

Comment: Ok, sorry, forget about this question. I inserted a debug log in the init script and found a typo in the `/etc/default/slapd` file. bump. Sorry for that, which took me some hours.